# MyEclipse Html(JS) editors cursor position changes randomly

Tags: myeclipse

I wrote use split and clone editors(show different parts), input one editor then view position is moved.
Same issue occuerd single and no splite mode.
When inputting source code, the cursor appears in a different position the moment the input stops.
Is it possible to fix it in settings?

Version.
MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench
Version: 2023.1.2
Build id: 16.0.0-20230705

MyEclipse add Translate plugin (pleiades eclipse plugin https://mergedoc.osdn.jp/#pleiades.html)

I wrote use split and clone editors(show different parts), input one editor then view position is moved.
Same issue occuerd single and no splite mode.
When inputting source code, the cursor appears in a different position the moment the input stops.
Is it possible to fix it in settings?

Version.
MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench
Version: 2023.1.2
Build id: 16.0.0-20230705

MyEclipse add Translate plugin (pleiades eclipse plugin https://mergedoc.osdn.jp/#pleiades.html)

Comment: Isn't this a paid product for which you should be receiving support?

Comment: I sent this problem few month ago, but no action product.